# To implement GCM requires the Google Play APK needs to be installed will restrict the number of user to use our android app?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, pubnub

GCM features is added with the Google Services. While developing android application to use the GCM the device require to have Google APK installed.

And I heard that some of the devices not having the Play Store APK or there is  no support for GCM. The devices like Amazon Fire phone, xiaomi and all.

I want to develop an app to support all the user. Is not like the user having installed Play Store APK can use our application.

I thought of using [pubnub](http://www.pubnub.com/). I don't know whether this is an right alternative. Because I am not finding any other way to overcome this issue.

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For Amazon Fire phone push notification, I think you need to use their Amazon Device Messaging. GCM is free compared to PubNub and better integration with Android devices. But PubNub or Parse is more universal, support more devices. So its your decision.

Comment: So to support Amazon Fire Phone I have to implement Amazon device messaging in the same code base. Is Like that?

Comment: What is the different between PubNub and Parse. Which is better to use. My ultimate aim is to support more users.

Comment: For max message length, PubNub support up to 32kb. Parse, it says it can be arbitrary large for Android: https://parse.com/questions/push-notification-json-length. But for latency, PubNub is more realtime, you can also implement Parse as data backend with PubNub: http://www.pubnub.com/blog/realtime-collaboration-sync-parse-api-pubnub/

Comment: As I explored pubnub is more reliable. So I will go with pubnub. I have fewer clarification related to that. When using Pubnub we wont get any push notification when the android app is not running. How to overcome this.

Comment: I think you can still receive push notifications while your app is not running, check out this post: http://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/380/can-my-android-app-receive-messages-while-inactive

Comment: Ok Thanks ztan. From my understanding without GCM using pubnub we can implement bidirectional communication from web server to mobile devices.